# dynamic adding into html element

Tags: javascript, html

A simple answer to this question is like this

```
document.getElementById("form").innerHTML += someHtmlString
```

And this works too. But my problem is, doing this cause the previous selected field to go to original state (in my case I was using < select > tag and the selected values were restored to original value).

What would be the possible solution. Is there any code that adds/appends in html tags (in my case a div tag) using only JS so that my previously selected options remains the same?

Regard

Answer (score 3):

Use normal DOM methods. That way the old HTML is never re-interpreted. Sample:

```
var div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = '<b>test</b>';
document.getElementById("form").appendChild(div);
```

Comment: +1, though a reference would probably be helpful ;)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Dynamically_modifying_XUL-based_user_interface

Comment: still gets the page refreshed :(

Answer (score 0):

Remember the selected item before appending HTML and after that select the item via JavaScript. Something like this should work:

```
var index = document.getElementById("idOfSelect").selectedIndex;
document.getElementById("form").innerHTML += someHtmlString;
document.getElementById("idOfSelect").options[index].selected = true;
```

Comment: but I do have a lot of select tags. I am adding select tags dynamically. Select on one option creates another select tags related to the first selected item.

Comment: So then, I would use jQuery to handle all of them. But it is not the best solution.